# sorting a json feed alphabetically

Tags: php, json, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of car names alphabetically. The list is based on a JSON feed that is sorted differently. Car names are nested in a deeper level of the feed. Here's what I have now without sorting:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents( 'http://api.autoit.dk/car/GetCarsExtended/391B093F-BB4A-45AA-BEFF-7B33842401EA' );

$myArray = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($myArray as $item):

    echo $item['FabrikatNavn'].' '.$item['ModelNavn'].' '.$item['VariantBetegnelse'];
```

?>

Anyone have a suggestion for how to make the list of car names show alphabetically? As you see, the feed comes from this url: http://api.autoit.dk/car/GetCarsExtended/391B093F-BB4A-45AA-BEFF-7B33842401EA

The car names that I want to sort it by are nested inside the feed like this: DealerCarExtended --> FabrikatNavn

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort($myArray)` function.

Check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: `sort()` only works on one-dimensional arrays but not ones like the one OP is dealing with

Comment: Apologies, they could try the array_multisort() function in that case

Comment: Which should be described in the post which I marked this one a duplicate of (or any of the other ones asking exactly the same question ;)

Comment: Ha I give up trying to help on this site

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate questions, but non-coders with very limited coding skills like me have difficulties with generic examples or examples from other contexts.. Bear with me ;-)